# Bitmap.GetPixel only returning 0s for R, G and B

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, console-application

I am loading an image inside a Console application using `Image.FromFile`.
After that, I am casting it to a `Bitmap` to be able to use the `Bitmap.GetPixel()` method.
Surprisingly, while looping through all the pixels, all what I am getting from the `GetPixel` is 0,0,0 for R,G,B.

To make sure that the image is well read from the file, I added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and I loaded the image inside a `PictureBox` to see the result, and the image is well seen.

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Here's how I am loading the image and showing it into a `PictureBox`:

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("image.png");

PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
{
    Image = img
};

Form frm = new Form
{
    Controls = { pb }
};

frm.ShowDialog();
```

Which shows the image as it is:

[image: Form shown after calling Form.ShowDialog]

And after that, I am getting the pixels like:

```
byte[] input = new byte[784];

for (int x = 0; x < 28; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 28; y++)
    {
        Color color = img.GetPixel(x, y);
        byte r = color.R;
        byte g = color.G;
        byte b = color.B;

        Console.Write($"{color.R},{color.G},{color.B}|||");
        input[x * 28 + y] = (byte)((((r + g + b) / 3)));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Note that the image size is 28x28px, and I have tried other images and I've got the same result.

What I expected that the results shows the real color values since I've used that method before and it worked perfectly, but now all the results printed to the console are zeros which I am finding it difficult to understand.

---

#### Edit:

Since the `PictureBox` is showing the real image representation, I tried to get the pixels from the `PictureBox.Image` like:

```
Color color = ((Bitmap)pb.Image).GetPixel(x, y);
```

This also didn't work and the results came back as zeros.

---

**What could be the reason behind this and how to fix it?**

Comment: Why is it a console-application?

Comment: @A.A.Because I don't really need to show anything. It's just a machine learning testing stuff and I only need the image data.

Comment: What file extention did you use before, when it worked? Can you test your algorithm with a JPG file please,

Comment: @A.A.I used it before with JPG and PNG and it always worked, even inside a console application as well.

Comment: Idea: Open your image in Paint or GIMP and check the RGB value of a random pixel

Comment: So it only fails with this one image? What are the details? (Size and pixel depths)

Comment: @TaW Image size is 28x28 and I didn't think of trying another image.. I just did and I got same result. I also added these info in the question for more clarifications.

Comment: @PaulKaram Can you try it with a JPG

Comment: PhotoShop or another program? If you have PhotoShop, open and save it again. See what comes out (I suppose the opposite, all *white*). What matters is the Alpha value.

Comment: The actual color is `[0,255,255,255]` or `[0,0,0,0]`. All transparent.

Comment: @Jimi After opening it in Photoshop and saving it again, it came out the same as a file. But when I tried in the code it actually gave the right values.

Comment: Note: Your image is transparent+black. If you don't evaluate the Alpha channel, all pixels *seem* black. More or less. Some semi-transparent pixels are there. It may just change the Alpha value to represent these, though. Different *techniques*.

Comment: Please post the actual png image!

Comment: @TaW Added in post and here's the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BJBI.png

Comment: @PaulKaram The image is black, due to transparency, the RGB delievers (0,0,0) which is black and in this case right. Try to use RGB values of 4th dimension, so you can get the alpha values too.

Comment: Thanks. There are indeed only black pixels in it. Many of them are transparent, which will let the picturebox's __backcolor show through__.  But the pixels all are black with varying values for alpha. You can use that as an indicator of real and fake black. So do add `color.A` in your tests!!

Comment: You can use color.A as a gauge of how much of the actual color and how much of a backcolor you chose shall be used. So the calculation could look like this: `red = ((255- color.A) * backcolor.R +  color.red * color.A )`

Comment: @TaW Thanks for all the information. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your image all color channels of all pixels **are** `0`, so you code actually works fine.

And most of the pixels also have an `alpha` of `0`, so they are **transparent**. Some are semi-transparent, anti-aliased pixels and a few are fully opaque.

Where transparent or semi-transprent pixels are, the backcolor will shine through.

If you want to recognize the really, non-transparent black pixels you need to test the alpha channel as well.

Here is a function that will create a composite color of a pixel's color and a given background color..:

```
Color Composite(Color color, Color backcolor)
{
    byte r = (byte)(((255 - color.A) * backcolor.R + color.R * color.A) / 256);
    byte g = (byte)(((255 - color.A) * backcolor.G + color.G * color.A) / 256);
    byte b = (byte)(((255 - color.A) * backcolor.B + color.B * color.A) / 256);
    Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
    return c2;
}
```

If you want the brightness of one of your pixels you could create a composite of its color with white. But, given the image you have, you could just as well use `color.A` directly..